# How to use hibernate-validator to validate interface parameters

Tags: bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have the following code to implement interface input parameter validation and now want to use hibernate-validator to do this

```java
public class Order
{
   private String orderNo;
   private String orderId;
   private String status;
   private String startTime;
   private String endTime;

   //getter and setter...
}
```

```java
public class OrderService
{
   public Object search(Order order) throws Exception
   {
      String message = "";
      if (order.getOrderId().isEmpty() && order.getOrderNo().isEmpty() && order.getStatus().isEmpty())
      {

         if (order.getStartTime().isEmpty() && order.getEndTime().isEmpty())
            message = "xxx";
      }

      if (!message.isEmpty())
         throw new Exception(message);

      Object result = null;
      // splice sql according to the attribute of order and get the result
      // result = sql query result
      return result;
   }
}
```

I tried to use Hibernate-validator's group to achieve this, but if there are more parameters, I need to write a lot of groups, which seems stupid. I have more than 100 interfaces, and will be added later, using Class-level constraints would be a good idea choice?

Below is the code trying to use Hibernate-validator's group implementation:

```java
public class Order
{
   @Empty(groups = One.class)
   @NotEmpty(groups = Two.class)
   private String orderNo;

   @Empty(groups = One.class)
   @NotEmpty(groups = Three.class)
   private String orderId;

   @Empty(groups = One.class)
   @NotEmpty(groups = Four.class)
   private String status;

   @NotEmpty(groups = One.class)
   private String startTime;

   @NotEmpty(groups = One.class)
   private String endTime;
}
```

```java
public class BeanValidatorUtils
{
   static Validator validator;

   static
   {
      HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure();
      ValidatorFactory factory = configuration.failFast(true).buildValidatorFactory();
      validator = factory.getValidator();
   }

   public static <T> void validation(T beanParam) throws AppException
   {
      if (!containsGroup(beanParam, One.class))
         return;

      Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> validate = validator.validate(beanParam, One.class);

      ConstraintViolation<T> constraintViolation = validate.iterator().next();
      String firstViolationMessage = constraintViolation.getMessage();

      if (!validate.isEmpty() && containsGroup(beanParam, Two.class))
      {
         validate = validator.validate(beanParam, Two.class);
      }
      if (!validate.isEmpty() && containsGroup(beanParam, Three.class))
      {
         validate = validator.validate(beanParam, Three.class);
      }

      if (!validate.isEmpty())
         throw new AppException(firstViolationMessage);
   }


   private static boolean containsGroup(Object bean, Class<?> groupClazz)
   {
      // ...
   }

}
```

Is there any other way to use Hibernate-validator to verify the Order in the search method?

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to make a validation decision based on the state of multiple properties of the `Order` you might want to explore these 3 options:

### Class level constraint

This would mean that you have to create your own constraint annotation (let's say `@ValidOrder`) and a corresponding `ValidOrderValidator`

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ValidOrderValidator.class })
@interface ValidOrder {
    String message() default "{message.key}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}

public class ValidOrderValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidOrder, Order> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Order order, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //null values are valid
        if ( order == null ) {
            return true;
        }
        if (order.getOrderId().isEmpty() && order.getOrderNo().isEmpty() && order.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
            if ( order.getStartTime().isEmpty() && order.getEndTime().isEmpty() ) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can also check this [post](https://in.relation.to/2017/03/02/adding-custom-constraint-definitions-via-the-java-service-loader/) for more detailed info on how to add new constraints using ServiceLoader.

### `@ScriptAssert` constraint

If your validation logic is relatively simple and you either already have a dependency or are willing to add one for a scripting engine, you can consider using the `@ScriptAssert` constraint. This is similar to the previous option but you don't need to create annotations and validator implementations you just have to put script logic into this constraint:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "groovy", script = "your validation script logic")
class Order {
    //...
}
```

### `@AssertTrue` constraint

Last but not least, one of the easiest ways to address such validation is to use `@AssertTrue` constraint on a getter with validation logic inside the `Order` class:

```
class Order {
    //...
    @AssertTrue
    public boolean isValidOrder() {
        // your validation logic
    }
}
```

Using any of these 3 approaches, you'd be able to make a validation decision based on multiple properties of the `Order` class.

As for [validation group](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0-jsr380/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence) usage - you can leverage using the groups if you need to pass the same `Order` object into multiple different methods/interfaces where a different set of validation rules need to be applied in each of them. Let's say, in one case, you have to create an order, and half of the fields can be `null`, but then in the other - you want to update it, and everything should be present.

Comment: thank you, I will try. When the verification fails, different messages need to be returned according to different conditions. If @AssertTrue is used, is there any other way to get the corresponding message besides reflection?

Comment: `@AssertTrue` only allows you to have one message. If the validation conditions are independent - you can create multiple methods marked with `@AssertTrue`, each having a different message. Otherwise, you would want to go with the custom annotation approach and look at this example here in the docs -https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#_the_code_constraintvalidatorcontext_code it shows you how to build messages and you can put your own message/template conditionally